# MySQL Filter results

Tags: sql, mysql, join, filter

I have a table in my SQL in the following structure called actions:

```
+----+--------+------+---------+
| id | action | type | user_id |
+----+--------+------+---------+
|  1 |      5 |    4 |       1 | 
|  2 |      6 |    4 |       1 | 
|  3 |      5 |    4 |       2 | 
|  4 |      0 |    0 |       2 | 
|  5 |      0 |    1 |       2 | 
+----+--------+------+---------+
```

and I have the users table like so:

```
+----+------------+----------------------------------+----------+
| id | fullname   | password                         | username |
+----+------------+----------------------------------+----------+
|  1 | Admin User | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx | admin    | 
|  2 | Arthur     | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx | arthur   | 
|  3 | john       | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx | john     | 
+----+------------+----------------------------------+----------+
```

I want to select all the actions from the action table except for the admins actions, I have tried doing:

```
SELECT * FROM actions WHERE user_id != 1;
```

But this does not work in some instances as the admin user_id is not always 1.

How would I go about selecting all the actions except the admin actions, I have tried messing around with JOINS but can not figure it out.

Hope you know what I mean.

Cheers

Eef

Comment: In order to answer this question, some more info is needed. Most important: if the admin does not always have `user_id = 1`, how can you know if a user is admin. Should we use `username = admin`?
As an aside remark: what does the `type` mean? If in two rows the `action` is the same, does that mean that `type` is the same as well? If this is the case, you might want to use a separate table for action types.

Comment: An admin user is always present in the system as it is the default user which is created at the install process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM actions inner join users
on actions.user_id = users.id 
WHERE users.username != "admin";
```

assuming all admins have username "admin"